# How to change Google search suggestions font color?

Tags: css, firefox, stylish

I'm looking for some help with the *.css* coding, I'd like to change [the Google search](https://www.google.com/), drop down list results font color from *purple* to *white* as you can see on the screenshot below:

[image: pic]

The purple color is hardly readable, the words I've written before as the results appear *purple* and I'd like them to be *white*. I've already changed the visited websites link color which was also *purple* following [this workaround](https://superuser.com/questions/726380/change-color-of-visited-links-in-chrome-33) and I'm wondering if the same workaround could be done for my issue?

Here's the code for the (Stylish) theme I'm trying to fix:

```css
@-moz-document regexp("https?://www.google.(com|([a-z]{2}))(.[a-z]{2})?."), regexp("https?://www.google.(com|([a-z]{2}))(.[a-z]{2})?/((\\?|webhp|search|gfe_rd|auth|gws_rd|#q|imghp|#gfe_rd|#safe|#pws|#tbs|#gws|#tbm).*)"), regexp("https?://encrypted.google.(com|([a-z]{2}))(.[a-z]{2})?/((\\?|webhp|search|gfe_rd|auth|gws_rd|#q|imghp|#gfe_rd|#safe|#pws|#tbs|#gws|#tbm).*)"), regexp("https?://encrypted.google.(com|([a-z]{2}))(.[a-z]{2})?.")
{
body{
    background: transparent url(https://s13.postimg.org/7thd5y3on/surftheme3.jpg) center top  fixed !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
/* Background image credits: http://www.thiswallpaper.com/  */
#fbar {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #333 !important;
}
#fbar a{
    color:#fff !important;
}
#fbar._Zvd > div#swml._HR > div._uIb > span{
    color:#fff !important;
}
#topabar{
    background: transparent !important;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc !important;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc !important;
}
#appbar {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
}
#resultStats{
    color:#fff;
}
.sfbgg{
    background: transparent !important;
}
body.vasq #hdtbSum{}
#center_col{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) !important;
    padding:10px !important;
}
._OKe{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) !important;
}
html > body#gsr.srp.tbo.vasq > div#main > div#cnt.big > div.mw > div#rcnt > div.col > div#center_col > div#res.med > div#search > div > div#ires > div#rso > div._NId > div.g.mnr-c.g-blk > div.kp-blk._kTi._Rqb._RJe > div#uid_0.r-ipzMKl8jpLfE.xpdbox.xpdclose.xpdns > div._OKe > div > div._Gtj.mod > div._Ixf > div.kno-fb-ctx > div > a.rl_item._Zxn > div._Vjf._Kjf._qkf._Wdh{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
}
#sb_ifc0{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
    color:#aaa !important;
}
a:link, .w, #prs a:visited, #prs a:active, .q:active, .q:visited, .kl:active, .tbotu {
    color: #f28d1b !important;
}
A:visited { color: #fff ! important }
.a, cite, cite a:link, cite a:visited, .cite, .cite:link, #_bGc > i, .bc a:link {
    color: #ccc !important;
    font-style: normal;
}
._OKe > div > div._Gtj.mod > div._Ixf > div.kno-fb-ctx > div > a.rl_item._Zxn._pkf > div._Vjf._Kjf._qkf._Wdh{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
}
._OKe > div > div._Gtj.mod > div._Ixf > div.kno-fb-ctx > div > a.rl_item._Zxn > div._Vjf._Kjf._qkf._Wdh{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
}
#center_col > div#res.med > div#search > div > div#ires > div#rso > div._NId > div.srg > div.g > div.rc > div.s > div > span.st > em{
    color:#fff !important;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}
body, div, p ,spam, small{
    color:#eee !important;
}
._OKe a.fl{
    color:#eee !important;
}
div#hplogo{background:url(https://s17.postimg.org/g335ase0v/surflogo3.png) no-repeat!important;background-size:269px 95px!important;height:95px!important;width:269px!important}
div#hplogo:not([title~=Google]){margin-top:50px!important}
div#hplogo>:not([nowrap='']){display:none!important}
img#hplogo{background:url(https://s17.postimg.org/g335ase0v/surflogo3.png) no-repeat!important;background-size:269px 95px!important;height:0!important;width:269px!important}
img#hplogo:not([title~=Google]){margin-top:50px!important}
img#hplogo>:not([nowrap='']){display:none!important}
.logocont > h1 > a#logo > img{
    display:none !important;
}
#logocont{
    width:140px !important;
    height:53px !important;
    background: url(https://s22.postimg.org/ijf0opcbl/surflogosmall.png) 5px 5px no-repeat;
}
#searchform.jhp.big > form#tsf.tsf > div.tsf-p > div.sfibbbc > div#sbtc.sbtc > div.sbibtd{
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}
.jsb{
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}
.gb_Ia {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background:#ddd !important;
}
#hdtb {
    background: transparent !important;
}
.sfbg{
    background: transparent !important;
}
.sfbgg{
    background: transparent !important;
}
.sfbgx{
    background: transparent !important;
}
#hdtbSum{
    background: transparent !important;
}
.sfbgx {
    border: 0px !important;
}
#hdtb{
    background: transparent !important;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    margin-top:-15px !important;
}
#hdtb-msb > div > div.hdtb-mitem.hdtb-imb > a{
    color:#fff !important;
}
#hdtb-s > div#hdtb-msb > div > a#hdtb-tls.hdtb-tl{
    color: #ccc !important;
}
a#abar_button_opt.hdtb-dd-b{
    color: #ccc !important;
}
div > a.hdtb-dd-b{
    color: #ccc !important;
}
#hdtb-msb .hdtb-mitem.hdtb-msel, #hdtb-msb .hdtb-mitem.hdtb-msel-pre {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #c6dbff !important;
    color: #c6dbff !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sbib_b > div#gs_lc0 > input{
    color:#fff !important;
}
.sbibtd > div#sfdiv.sbibod.sbhcn.sbfcn > div.lst-c > div.gstl_0.sbib_a > div#sb_ifc0.sbib_b  {
    background:#777 !important;
}
ul.sbsb_b > li.sbsb_c.gsfs{
    background:#333 !important;
}
g-inner-card._dCh._KBh  {
    background:#333 !important;
}
g-inner-card{
    background:#333 !important;
}
#gb_70.gb_9e.gb_Ia.gb_yb{
    background:#333 !important;
}
.tsf-p > div.jsb > center > input{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important;
}
.tsf-p > div.jsb > center > input{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) !important;
    color:#111 !important;
}
a.gb_P{
    color:#fff !important;
}
#main.content > div#cnt.big > div.mw > div#rcnt > div.col > div#center_col > div#extrares.med > div#botstuff > div > div#brs > g-section-with-header > div._ojo > h3.med._wI{
    color:#fff !important;
}
._uwb{
    color:#fff !important;
}
div._qhf._grf{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
}
div._Zjj > div{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those Google search suggestions, which you have visited before, appear to be settable with CSS like this:

```css
.sbsb_a, .sbpqs_a {
    color: yellow !important;
}
```

-- which was determined by painful use of Firefox's debugging tools.

---

[image: resulting screenshot]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm.